# UDP message contains odd characters

Tags: arrays, vb.net, udp, plc, udpclient

We have a machine with a PLC that broadcasts UDP messages constantly. I can capture it with this code

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Text

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim port As Integer = 44036
        Dim UDPClient As UdpClient = New UdpClient()

        UDPClient.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket,
         SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, True)
        UDPClient.Client.Bind(New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port))

        Try

            Dim iepRemoteEndPoint As IPEndPoint = New _
            IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 11000)
            Dim strMessage As String = String.Empty
            Do
                Dim bytRecieved As Byte() =
               UDPClient.Receive(iepRemoteEndPoint)
                strMessage = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytRecieved)

                Console.WriteLine("Message: " _
               + strMessage)

            Loop While (strMessage <> "exit")
            UDPClient.Close()


        Catch e As Exception

            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString())
        End Try

        Console.WriteLine("Press Any Key to Continue")
        Console.ReadKey()


    End Sub
```

The message looks like this:

> ?☻☺ 10:57:56 13/10/21 _/`∟☻☺  y?        \     ⌂☺                       ☺(10) Farm Name            @*                                     ☺ Pee Wee                                    ☺ Dirt                    ♥☺ EXlarge                ☺                  ♥☺ EXlarge                ☺                  ♥☺ EXlarge                ☺                  ♥☺ Large                  ☺                  ♥☺ Large                  ☺  ♥☺ Large                  ☺                   ☺ Lt. Large              ☺☺ Lt. Large                                  ☺ Lt. Large              ☺ Large                                     ☺☺ Large                   ♥☺ Large            ☺☺    ☺ ☺              ☺☺ ☺ Large                ☺ ☺ EXlarge                                   ☺☺ EXlarge                 ☺ EXlarge                                    ☺ EXlarge                 ☺ EXlarge                                   ☺☺ EXlarge                 ☺ Medium                                     ☺ Jumbo

---

I'm pretty confident that the symbols represent numbers, because we have software (supplied by the machine manufacture) that displays this exact message, but the for each word there are numbers instead of the smiley faces I see.

Is it possible that they are sending the messages with some of the numbers in a different encoding (this was ASCII)? Or is it possible to send an array of bytes within a byte array? I've been trying to solve this for a while with no luck

Here is a screenshot from the software
[egg_details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ynJ4.png)

Here is what I got with this code

```
strMessage = BitConverter.ToString(bytRecieved)
```

```
===============================================================
5D-EF-01-00-31-35-3A-35-30-3A-34-35-00-31-33-2F-31-30-2F-32-31-00-64-4A-63-3A-02-00-00-00-37-16-14-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-01-28-31-30-29-20-48-69-64-64-65-6E-20-41-63-72-65-73-20-46-61-72-6D-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-F1-B5-02-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-01-00-4C-65-61-6B-72-20-20-20-20-20-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-01-00-53-6D-61-6C-6C-20-20-20-20-20-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-01-00-4C-61-72-67-65-20-20-20-20-20-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-01-00-4C-61-72-67-65-20-20-20-20-20-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-01-01-00-4C-74-2E-20-4C-61-72-67-65-20-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-01-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-01-01-00-45-58-6C-61-72-67-65-20-20-20-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-02-01-00-45-58-6C-61-72-67-65-20-20-20-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-01-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-02-01-00-4C-61-72-67-65-20-20-20-20-20-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-01-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-01-00-4C-61-72-67-65-20-20-20-20-20-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-01-00-45-58-6C-61-72-67-65-20-20-20-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-01-01-00-45-58-6C-61-72-67-65-20-20-20-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-01-01-00-45-58-6C-61-72-67-65-20-20-20-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-01-00-45-58-6C-61-72-67-65-20-20-20-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-02-01-00-4C-61-72-67-65-20-20-20-20-20-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-01-01-00-4C-61-72-67-65-20-20-20-20-20-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-01-01-00-45-58-6C-61-72-67-65-20-20-20-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-01-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-03-01-00-45-58-6C-61-72-67-65-20-20-20-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-01-01-00-00-00-01-00-01-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-01-03-01-00-45-58-6C-61-72-67-65-20-20-20-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-01-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-01-01-00-4C-74-2E-20-4C-61-72-67-65-20-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-02-01-00-4C-61-72-67-65-20-20-20-20-20-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-01-01-00-4C-61-72-67-65-20-20-20-20-20-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-01-00-4D-65-64-69-75-6D-20-20-20-20-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-01-00-4A-75-6D-62-6F-20-20-20-20-20-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-5F-5F-5F-5F-5F-5F-5F-5F-5F-5F-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-5F-5F-5F-5F-5F-5F-5F-5F-5F-5F-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
=======================================================================
```

Comment: Do you have documentation on the message formatting?  Or is what you're "trying to solve" reverse engineering the message? Without additional info, I'd guess that the message format is a proprietary mixture of string and binary data. The white smiley faces could be delimiters, given the prevalence of them.

Comment: Yes, basically I'm trying to reverse engineer it. I do not think whoever programmed this was trying to hide anything

Comment: I don't have any documentation. I'm flying blind. The machine is from a big company, likely programmed by some guy 20 + years ago

Comment: Let's have a look at the raw bytes, in hex, not in whatever encoding whatever you've opened the file in has chosen to use. Take a screenshot of a hex editor showing the bytes (dump them to file raw)

Comment: Just because it could be a proprietary format doesn't mean it's "trying to hide" anything. If it's old enough, it could pre-date xml and json. But even if not, there are legitimate reasons to not use those, for instance they tend to be 'wordy', if there's a large amount of these UDP messages flying about, a smaller message format will have less impact on network traffic, utilization, etc. Or could be it was considered an internal format and usage, so no need to use a standardized interchange format.

Comment: In addition to @CaiusJard suggestion for hex formatted data, please also provide the display from the manufacturer's software ("for each word there are numbers instead of the smiley faces") for comparison and possible interpretation/translating, etc.

Comment: (I think the smiley faces will have been added by your console encoding tbh; frankly Console.Writing any bunch of bytes and then copypasta'ing them is a guaranteed way to ruin any chances of picking the data apart at the byte level)

Comment: Screenshot added. I'll post the raw bytes once I figure out how to get them